# Find string with added whitespace in CSV header with Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, csv

I am using the following code to `puts` a column to the screen:

```
CSV.foreach(
  response_file,
  :col_sep => "\t",
  :encoding => 'BOM|UTF-16LE:UTF-8',
  :quote_char => '"',
  :headers => true
) do |column|
  puts column[/\sPlease help us improve by telling us why you chose that ranking.\s/]
end
```

The actual header name is `Please help us improve by telling us why you chose that ranking.`    with one space and a tab at the beginning, and an additional space at the end.

However, this isn't finding the right column. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`column[/\sPlease help us improve by telling us why you chose that ranking.\s/]` is wrong.

Because of `:headers => true`, CSV is going to return a hash for each record read.

A hash key for each column will be a string consisting of the contents of that column heading. A key can not be a regex unless that same regex was used as the column heading.

I'd tell CSV to return an array by using `:headers => false` and then index into the array to extract that column's information. Then the headers won't matter.

This is the general idea:

```
require 'csv'

headers_read = false
CSV.foreach(
  'test.csv',
  :headers => false
) do |column|
  unless headers_read
    headers_read = true
    next
  end
  puts column[0]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a `Regexp` but `CSV::Row#[]` expects a `String`. This should work:

```
CSV.foreach(response_file, ...) do |row|
  puts row[" \tPlease help us improve by telling us why you chose that ranking. "]
end
```